# merging javascript get with css div

Tags: javascript, css

Epic failure... I would like to use java script to avoid repetitive lines of styling the page. It worked okay with html, without css div. Could you please help! Thank you so much!

```js
function getheaderHTML() {
 document.writeln('  <div id="nav">');
 document.writeln('    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
 document.writeln('  <div id="header">');
 document.writeln('    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
}

function getfooterHTML() {
 document.writeln('  <div id="footer">');
 document.writeln('    &#169;2016');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-image: url("background.jpg");
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
p {
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}

a:link {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:visited {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
#container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
 float: left;
 max-width: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 width: 90%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<script>
 <!--
  getheaderHTML();
 //-->
</script>
  <div id="lcolumn">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rcolumn">
    <p><Hello</p>
  </div>
<script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
  getfooterHTML();
 //-->
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: For future reference: StackOverflow tells you to add more information over code for a reason - to help explain your question. Rather than repeating your question three times, try to explain the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You got these two errors!

```
   {
      "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: getheaderHTML is not defined",
      "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
      "lineno": 112,
      "colno": 3
    }
    {
      "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: getfooterHTML is not defined",
      "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
      "lineno": 123,
      "colno": 3
    }
```

> Because your script is loading at the end of html file. That's why `getheaderHTML()` and `getfooterHTML()` are not found and not executed. To make it **workable** you have to **load your script before calling these javascript function** in html file.

***See and Run this snippet***

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 background-image: url("background.jpg");
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
p {
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #808080;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}

a:link {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
 color: inherent;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
a:visited {
 color: #B2AB19;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
}
#container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
 float: left;
 max-width: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 250px;
 border: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 width: 90%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script>
function getheaderHTML() {
 document.writeln('  <div id="nav">');
 document.writeln('    <a href="index.html">number 1</a>｜<a href="students.html">number 2</a>');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
 document.writeln('  <div id="header">');
 document.writeln('    <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
}

function getfooterHTML() {
 document.writeln('  <div id="footer">');
 document.writeln('    &#169;2016');
 document.writeln('  </div>');
}  
</script>

<div id="container">
<script>
  getheaderHTML();
</script>
  <div id="lcolumn">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rcolumn">
    <p><Hello</p>
  </div>
<script>
 getfooterHTML();
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May I have one more question? Is it possible to put the javascript in an external file and still load your script before calling these javascript function?

Comment: Yes you can. just put the <script src="myscripts.js"></script> before calling the javascript function

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="get.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body lang="zh-hk">
<div id="container"
<script>
 <!--
  getheaderHTML();
 //-->
</script>
  <div id="lcolumn">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rcolumn">
    <p><Hello</p>
  </div>
<script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
  getfooterHTML();
 //-->
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>